# How to make "long press" on button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote this code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Long Press</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="refresh_page">
<button>long press to refresh</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do that `long press on button` by mouse to refresh the page.but without using javascript.

Can any one help me ?

Comment: You could use the `mouseup` event

Comment: You can not do it without `JavaScript`.

Comment: Eh? You tagged your question with `javascript` and `jquery` - then edited the question to say "without using javascript"...

Comment: LOL! Nobody said it was easy... make it with javascript.... but without it! (QUANTUM JS)

Answer (score 4):

If you REALLY don't want to use javascript - you can get long click in Flash!

actionscript 3:

```
private function mouseup(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseup);
    myTimer.reset();
}
private function showInfo(event:TimerEvent):void{
    //long press code
}
private function mousedown(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myTimer.start();
}
```

Impossible question = answered

Comment: You have indeed done the impossible: you made me upvote an answer that recommends using Flash.  I salute you good sir

Comment: I hope no-one thinks I am *actually* recommending Flash...

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this counting time that there's between `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.

This seems a duplicated question: [How to apply long click event and doubleclick event on the same element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539329/how-to-apply-long-click-event-and-doubleclick-event-on-the-same-element-in-javas)

**[JS FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cmwzQ/1/)**

Comment: no java script dude, he updated the question

Comment: We've already said that this cannot be achived **without** `javascript`. And This Question is tagget as `javascript`.

Comment: answer is good but not at this question

Comment: meh... i've tried it :'( boohoo