# Detect long press on text in page [Chrome Extension Development]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. I want to show a popup when long pressed on the current open page or tab. How do I detect when a text on the page is long pressed?

Comment: There's an answer with a working demo here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539329/how-to-apply-long-click-event-and-doubleclick-event-on-the-same-element-in-javas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Buley describes in this post: [How to detect a long press on a div in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586883/how-to-detect-a-long-press-on-a-div-in-jquery), you have to watch both mouseup and mousedown events and calculate the difference.

```
(function() { 

// how many milliseconds is a long press?
var longpress = 3000;
// holds the start time
var start;

jQuery( "#pressme" ).on( 'mousedown', function( e ) {
    start = new Date().getTime();
} );

jQuery( "#pressme" ).on( 'mouseleave', function( e ) {
    start = 0;
} );

jQuery( "#pressme" ).on( 'mouseup', function( e ) {
    if ( new Date().getTime() >= ( start + longpress )  ) {  
       // If you want to get the text of the element, use jQuery's element.text()
       alert('long press! You pressed: ' + $(this).text());   
    } else {
       alert('long press! You pressed: ' + $(this).text());   
    }
    } );
}());
```

Although this is a jQuery example, this is also possible without(see Walk's example)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. but there is a slight difference. I want to get the text on which mouse long pressed. It might be any text on the page.

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to return the value of the text on which you click?

Comment: yes. I want to return the text on which user clicked

Comment: I've edited the example. Clicking the button should now return the text of the element. This is an example with a button but you can bind this to any element you want;)

Comment: I checked the code. There is a tiny problem. I just want the text only like if a paragraph tag has "This is me" value in it and when i click for more than 1 sec on "me" , i need the text "me " not the whole "This is me " sentence. just the word. Thanks for the help.

Comment: A quick google search and i think i've found exactly what you need. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text

Comment: yeah tried the code.... it works thanks. There is an error when pressed on "About 19,30,000 results (0.40 seconds) " on google search page. when clicked on "about"
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': The offset 4294967295 is larger than the node's length (23).

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are doing wrong without an example. The link i posted also has other examples in it. You could try those. If it's still not working, please post an example with code to clearify your problem.

Comment: okay. I will post the whole code. Let me try all the examples

Comment: Hi I got a weird behavior.. dunno what's wrong. I viewed your good in jsfiddle ang it works like charm... but when I try to use your code on my mouseup event is not firing. Its like lost.. something like that.